# Comboxes items compare and match -VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have  2 excel sheets :  one containing the source data and  one contains the goal data. i have  created userform that contains comboboxes(dropdownlists)and  import button .

there are  comboboxes that contain the names of the first row of the Source sheet  and other comboboxes that contain the names of the first row of the goal sheet.

i want to compare the names in  the comboboxes ( source and goal names)  and match them if they are equal
than when i click on import Button , everything in the source excel  sheet  will be imported in the goal excel sheet in  the right place.
how can i do that ?

I TRIED THIS CODE

```
dim sh =ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sourcedata")
dim sh2= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("goaldata")
dim i,j as integer

for i = 1 to Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
for j = 1 to Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh2.Range("1:1"))  
     if sh.cells(1,i).value = sh2.cells(1,j).value then

          Me.comboBox1.value = sh.cells(1,i)
          Me.comboBox2.value = sh2.cells(1,j)
          Me.comboBox3.value = sh.cells(1,i)
          Me.comboBox4.value = sh.cells(1,j) 
end if
next
next 
end sub
```

the problem that i get usually the same value in all comboboxes.
i want to get in all comboboxes the names of the rows in both sheets.

for example i have the rows names of the  Source sheet   : Date , Event and place
the rows names in the  goal sheet are : Date and  Event only
for example : in combobox1.value=  Date should also in comboBox2.value = Date  (because Date exists in both sheets)
combBox3.value = Event and Combobox 4.value  should be Event

I want to insert Combobox5.value = place ( combobox 5 contain the names that exist only in one sheet and  they don't have any match )

Any help?

Comment: You should post the code  that you tried.

Comment: i have posted the Code. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the 3 combobox part but not completely the "which data should be copied" part so let's already advance on the combobox part.

Some notes about your code:

- When you don't mention a dataType in you dim the vars are by default in variant type => e.g. dim i => is the same as dim i as variant. although not always a problem it could lead to unexpected behaviour;
- The "combobox.value" is to get the selected value of the combobox, not to add items to it. Looking at your desc. and code I think you intented to add items.

So hereunder a revised version based on my assumptions. instead of using the "add ..Item" I just assigned the sheet cells to arrays as we can then manipulate these directly in memory, allowing operations like comparing, copying, etc.. to be performed much faster.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arr, arr2
    arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:c1").Value2
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    
    arr2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:c1").Value2
    Me.ComboBox2.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr2)
    
    Dim i As Long, arr3, ii As Long: ii = 1
    ReDim arr3(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(1, i) <> arr2(1, i) Then
            arr3(1, ii) = arr(1, i)
            ii = ii + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Me.ComboBox3.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr3)
End Sub
```

Have a look at it and let me know how it went.